# using chrome view instead of default webview in cordova

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cordova, webview

I am quite new to cordova/Phonegap.I used InAppBrowser API to connect to apprtc.appspot.com which is a webrtc demo site.

```
iabRef = window.open('https://apprtc.appspot.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

I am using a Nexus 5 phone to test this behavior. I feel its taking the default android webview instead of chrome browser intent. If that's the case how can I change it to chrome browser intent ? So that the webrtc demo site opens well (without getUserMedia() failing).

Any inputs on this will be of great help to me.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 3):

Android webview not support WebRTC see this link https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

But intel crosswalk provide true WebRTC for  android (hybrid,web app) see this link https://crosswalk-project.org/