# DART registerElement

Tags: dart

I'm trying custom elements in DART, using the belo registration, which has worked very well.

```
document.registerElement(CustomElement.tag, CustomElement)
```

After building the pub, the file worked fine in Chrome, but not with Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I got the below error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: $document.registerElement is not a function
```

and the following error in Internet Explorer:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'registerElement'
```

any thoughts!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the polyfills for browsers without native custom elements support.

in `pubspec.yaml` you need

```
dependencies:
  web_components: any
```

and in your entry page you need a script tag like

```
<script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll test it once be back to home, but have a doubt, I'm using my own build custom element, not te deprecated web_componenent model, plus, everything run smooth with Chrome, I just run it in office, in 2 devices, the output in Chrome is perfect, but nothing in other browsers! Safari shows white page here for all sites, so can not tell if Safari work like Chrome or others. thanks

Comment: It seems you mix up `web_component` with `web_ui`. Polymer is based on a set of standards like Shadow DOM, Custom Elements, HTML Imports. You are just using the 'Custom Element' part which is (as the other parts) not yet supported in several browsers (beside Chrome, not sure about the status in Firefox).
The polyfills add this missing functionality to browsers which don't have these functionality implemented natively yet.
See http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components for more details.

Comment: Output in Opera is perfect, same as Chrome!

Comment: I have never used Opera but it seems it also supports Custom Elements http://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-20/ (`Opera 20 for Mac and Windows (based on Chromium 33) is out!`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll check in home, and confirm if this gone fine :)

Comment: I liked to add this note, that I just found for Internet Explorer and Android webview for Android less than 4.4 the "<script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>" should be declared BEFORE the "<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>" to run smoothly, for firefox, sequence of the 2 codes is not important.

Comment: I had a doubt... I packaged my app as Chrome app, the customs elements did not work there! any thought!

Comment: Dartium, Chrome or both?

Comment: I checked it in Chrome, it worked only after adding before all other scripts the follwoing one: "<script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script> "

Comment: I still have issues that custom elements not working in webkit after packaging an Android app,in Android editions before KitKat (4.4), any thought!

Comment: Android WebKit before KitKat 4.4 is just not supported by the polyfills. Crosswalk seems to be a technology to work on Android before 4.4 but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104163, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027555,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808836, https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/202 might help.